# Firemonkey default Windows style?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Delphi XE6

When I create a new Firemonkey Desktop Application, and drop a TGrid on the form, and edit the default style, it shows the TImage as:

"StyleBook1Windows 7style.png"

Where is the *.vsf file for this image. I would like to export the PNG from it and modify it and create a new style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create your own style, you can get the bitmap used by an existing style using the following steps.

1. Launch the Bitmap Style Designer from the Delphi IDE menu - Tools |
   Bitmap Style Designer.
2. Then from the Style Designer, select File | Open followed by selecting the .vsf file you wish to extract the bitmap from. You'll find a bunch of these in your `c:\users\public\documents\embarcadero\studio\17.0\Styles` directory. Change the 17.0 in the directory name to 14.0 for Delphi 6.
3. From the list of objects on the left, select Images. Expand images and you should see style.png
4. Now select Export (which is above the bitmap) which allows you to save the bitmap to a file

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need the original file. If you click on the SourceLink property (click on the (TBitmapLinks)--not on the '...' button)) the Bitmaplinks Editor opens. There you can upload your own png file and define the areas you want to use in the style.

Comment: I actually do need the original. Like I said in my question, i want to modify it